# i need the future to return an image with the url from server

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get url from my Firebase inform of a string and i want the process to wait for the http request to complete before proceeding because this url is to be used as the image url.

I want to make an app that automatically takes an image from a server and displays it automatically.Someone please help

I have tried future builder but i get the above error

```
    class _MyScreensHomeState extends State<MyScreensHome> {
  Future<String> _getmorningScreen1() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        'https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/Shows/Morning_Show/Screen1.json');
    final String latestResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    return latestResponse;
  }

  Widget _defaultImage() {
    return Image.asset(
      'assets/Kiss_default.jpg',
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
    );
  }

  Widget _connectingImage() {
    return Image.asset(
      'assets/Kiss_default.jpg',
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Screen 2'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getmorningScreen1(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                _defaultImage();
                break;
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                _connectingImage();
                break;
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Error:${snapshot.error}');
                } else {
                  return Image.asset(
                    (snapshot.data).toString(),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                  );
                }
                break;
              default:
                Card(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('No Images to Display'),
                  ),
                );
            }
            return Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: https://i.postimg.cc/NjZGz6fS/Studio-Screens-Wake-01.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load 
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:221
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync 
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:464
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load 
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:449
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "https://i.postimg.cc/NjZGz6fS/Studio-Screens-Wake-01.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#966e8(), name: "https://i.postimg.cc/NjZGz6fS/Studio-Screens-Wake-01.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Remove Generic from `FutureBuilder<String>`, make it plain `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: i didbut now im gettng a new error.

Comment: so how do i get the url in the end?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Also your future will fireup every second if you keep the `Future` method inside.

Comment: I/flutter ( 6819): The offending widget is: FutureBuilder<String>
I/flutter ( 6819): Build functions must never return null. To return an empty space that causes the building widget to
I/flutter ( 6819): fill available room, return "new Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as
I/flutter ( 6819): possible, return "new Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error as I said in comment, difference between your `Future` method and `FutureBuilder` Generics. They must be same type.

Another one is as I realize with additional error log, you are not returning any `Widget` inside some cases and default.

So do like this:

```
switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.none:
                    return _defaultImage();
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return _connectingImage();
                  case ConnectionState.done:
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('Error:${snapshot.error}');
                    } else {
                      return Text('Result:${snapshot.data}');
                    }
                    break;
                  default:
                    return Card(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text('No Images to Display'),
                      ),
                    );
                }
```

Edit: Another problem is with your edited code:

```
case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Error:${snapshot.error}');
                } else {
                  return Image.network( // => Change this into .network
                    (snapshot.data).toString(),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                  );
                }
```

Because you are putting `url`, not a `relative path`.

Comment: so far your changeshave helped....now for the million dollar question

Comment: @ClioTech I edited the answer, just change the `Image.asset` into `Image.network` in that specific place.

Comment: @ClioTech if your issue is solved, please accept the answer and close the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** is your FutureBuilder knows the data type but your Future function is sending dynamic instead of string.

Just update your `_getmorningScreen1` function like that `Future<String> _getmorningScreen1() ...`